# How to get collections and docs from Firestore Database?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections, document

In my firestore database,

there is a users list contains information for `name`, `email`

I want to read data and display it...

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccount = require("C:/Users/santo/Downloads/sample.json");

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

let fs = admin.firestore();
      const santosh = await fs.collection('users').doc('ANCyBKH2yeh3njsiDJ6vegFUr2').get();
  console.table([santosh.data()]);
```

but I need all docs data i.e., I need the email and name of all the docs

Hwo can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fetch all the documents in users collection and iterate through the snapshot.

```
const db = admin.firestore();

(async function () {
  const snapshot = await db.collection("users").get();

  for (const doc of snapshot.docs) {
    console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data().name, doc.data().email);
  }
})();
```